# Is this pineapple plant dead?

Tags: plant-health, growth

I planted a pineapple plant. Some leaves died. Tips of others died too. But, as you can see in the picture, most of it is green. It has been this way for months, and no new leaves grow. Is it dead? If not, what should I do to encourage growth?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's  not dead at all - but there are some dead areas at the tips of the leaves, and what looks like one completely dead leaf. Trim off the dead areas and the dead leaf,but don't prune. These plants grow from the centre, and if you're in the northern hemisphere, it will now rest and not do very much. Even indoors, though, it needs as much as sun as it can get, but should not be anywhere near a heat source like a radiator or fire. As far as watering goes, only water when the surface of the potting soil feels dry to the touch, and water well, emptying away any excess water in an outer tray or pot after 30 minutes, never leave it sitting in water. Further information here, https://www.todayshomeowner.com/how-to-grow-pineapples-as-houseplants/ - the bit you're interested in is towards the end. You'll note the size of pot required, and the fact that these plants benefit from being outdoors during summer.

I'm rather curious as to the cause of the white lines or what look like scratch marks on some of the central leaves...

Comment: I'm less optimistic, but from photos I can not see much. Pineapples are monocots, so the central buds is very important. If it dies, the plant dies. The dry part in the middle makes me worry. Note: like palms, pineapples and other perennial monocots, have the central bud very protected by "old" leaves (and hairs).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure its dead in the middle, there's one  little area that looks dry and brown, but impossible to say from this picture whether that's the central growth point or not. If it is, you're right,its likely on its way out.  But there might also be evidence of a pup to the left and behind the main growth...

Comment: The pup doesn't seem a pineapple. IMO an other pot behind it

Comment: The central bud doesn't seem very promising at all. On the other hand, the pineapple has been in a more-or-less similar state for a long time. I planted it in mid-April of this year.

Comment: If the central growth point has died, the whole plant will die back in an obvious fashion, so if that happens, its a goner...

Answer (score 2):

I by far am not an expert, this is more of an opinion than advice. I would prune it back, chop off all the dead. My Aunt says dead leaves sucke the life out of a healthy plant. Maybe do a quick Google search of what type of fertilizer would be good for it, to give it a boost. Good luck.

Comment: Well its an interesting concept, but dead leaves don't 'suck the life out' of a plant, they're not doing anything, they're dead. Best removed so they don't fall and maybe rot on the top of the soil if the plant's in a pot, but otherwise, they're usually removed for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: @Bamboo or to block the spreading of diseases. But this case doesn't seems the case

Answer (score 2):

The pineapple has recently started growing! [image]

Answer (score 2):

Update. Here is what it looks like now. It helps that I now keep it outside in a warmer climate.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The yellowing is from over watering or pests. I cut my plant back because it got severely over water from the hurricane rains we got here in Va. I'm going to check the roots for rot and depot mine. Finger crossed!!!