# Should I repot these pineapples?

Tags: fertilizer, repotting

I planted both of these pineapples from ones I bought in the store. Are they fine in their current pots or should they be repotted? Any other care tips for them? They have been inside for a while, but it has just now gotten hot enough for them to be outside (in Georgia).

For this one, see also [Is this pineapple plant dead?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/35851/is-this-pineapple-plant-dead) 
[image]

[image]